# PHP undefined variable (possible duplicate?)

Tags: php, variables, undefined, notice

I'm making a script for changing e-shop prices. This is my settings panel (key variables)

```
// --- <SETTINGS PANEL> --- //
$safe_mode = true;
$safer_mode = false;
$safe_cycle = false;
$file_loc = 'cata.txt';
$skuindex = '1';
$nameindex = '2';
$priceindex = '0';
$rowdelimiter = '_';
$celldelimiter = '-';
// --- </SETTINGS PANEL> --- //
```

Later on I'm using my safe_mode variable here:

```
function updateit($pricus,$skus,$namef)
{
 if($safer_mode)
 {
 $querytoup = "UPDATE product SET margin = '', vat_id = '1', cost = '', price = '".$pricus."' WHERE sku LIKE '".$skus."' AND name LIKE '".$namef."';";
 }
 else
 {
  $querytoup = "UPDATE product SET margin = '', vat_id = '1', cost = '', price = '".$pricus."' WHERE sku LIKE '".$skus."' AND name LIKE '".$namef."%';";
 };
 echo('Establishing connection...<br>');
 updateexec($querytoup);
};
```

updateexec(); then executes a bit more complex function I don't want to paste here. The problem is that I'm getting this kind of error/notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: safer_mode in /var/www/doit.php on line 54
```

Line 54 is exactly the if($safer_mode) line.
So where did I go wrong? I know this stuff happens when you declare a variable inside a loop/function that doesn't run under some conditions so it's undeclared, but I'm declaring $safe_mode **outside any functions**, the settings panel is in the beginning of the file. I'm not running any includes or requires.
Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Each function has its own local variable scope. Anything declared outside isn't automatically mirrored into functions.

Comment: PHP scope isn't like JavaScript (I only guess familiarity with JS because of the `;` after closing `}`, which is not used in PHP)

Comment: You would have to pass that variable as a parameter into the `updateit()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not defined inside functions in PHP. In order to use them, you have to declare them using the global keyword.

```
function updateit($pricus,$skus,$namef)
{
    global $safer_mode;
    if($safer_mode)
    {
```

In general, using global variables in functions is bad practice. It should be avoided in the majority of cases.

Comment: But it's better to pass the variable as a value into `updateit()`. The `global` keyword should be avoided because it causes side effects that are very hard to spot (until something stops working because of a seemingly unrelated change somewhere else).

Comment: Again, I'm not defining it **inside** a function, but outside. I'm just using it in the function. Fixed it with passing the variable as a parameter, the weird thing is that it used to work on older versions of PHP.

Comment: You are right, I should have mentionned it.